# Live JPEG stream from webcam without using Flash

Tags: javascript, webcam, feed

I have been asked to create a Wordpress site where the homepage is similar to this http://www.sagmeisterwalsh.com. It features what appears to be a live Jpeg stream from a webcam. The site is also responsive so works across multiple devices.

I have no experience of working with web cameras and would like a few pointers/links on how I might achieve this. Any solution would have to rely on Javascript and not Flash so it works on mobile devices as well as desktops.

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance

Comment: This question is too broad to be a good fit for on SO. Check the linked site's source. Or check this out to access webcam data: https://github.com/PeeHaa/ScreenCast

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you have a bunch of JPEG images using some creative javascript, but it won't be easy. You can always use a setInterval loop to place an image into place and swap it with the previous one, but depending on your frame rate, this might not go as smooth as you hope.

Also bear in mind that the images will have to be loaded, so you might want to delay the display of the images and buffer them before trying to swap them into place (for example not make the stream "live", but delay it a few seconds so the images can be buffered).